# Data loss during MongoDB replica set failover

Tags: mongodb, failover

I have a Go client that continually inserts sensor data into a MongoDB replica set 30 times per sec. I ran a failover test on my 3-member set using majority write concern (while still firing the inserts). The failover process took only 2 seconds, but afterward I realized some data samples were missing. They were not in the database or in the old primary's rollback file--completely missing.

In general, how can I assure no data loss (or minimal loss) in MongoDB during failover? I'm new to MongoDB. Are there commercially available MongoDB management modules for this (I have the free edition)? E.g. can MongoDB store incoming data temporarily during failovers and later persist the data to the database? I don't want to resort to handling failovers on the client--I want failovers to be transparent to the client.

Comment: That's odd, to say the least. During an election, there is no primary, hence no data can be written. I don't know go the slightest bit, but the driver should report the problem of not being able to write. In Java, you'd catch the exception and in the most naive approach wait for 5 seconds and retry the write.

Comment: I know the replica set won't accept writes during elections, but is there any log (in memory or on disk) in MongoDB that captures writes temporarily during the process? I wanted the solution to be language-independent and solved by MongoDB if possible.

Comment: Jesus, if a host is down, how should that work? If you send data, you have to make sure wether it is sent or not. If the driver reports a problem (which it will most likely do when the replica set doesn't have a primary), *you* have to deal with it. For some applications, loosing 3 seconds of data might be acceptable. Resend the data if not.

Comment: I actually had a look at the go driver. The example clearly states that an error is returned if an insert fails. If I get that right (knowing s... about Go), you can check wether there was an error, do a [`time.sleep(5*time.Second)`](http://golang.org/pkg/time/#Sleep), try to resend the data and if that fails, deal with the seemingly fatal problem.

Comment: Could you provide a link to the failed insert example?

Comment: It is in the "Example" section of http://labix.org/mgo